# method call which in error returns for loop numbers of iteration

Tags: ruby

Here's the code I have which takes a string and reverse it

```
    name = "I CAN REVERSE THIS"

    def reverse_string(name_string)
      string_arr = []
      string_arr = name_string.split('')

      for i in 1..(string_arr.length)
        new_string = "#{new_string}#{string_arr[-i]}"
      end

      #return new_string
    end

    new_name = reverse_string(name)
    puts new_name
```

Why does my reverse_string function returns "1..18" if no return actions is called inside the function, but returns expected results if return action is called?

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite [reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-reverse) method??

Comment: New to Ruby; was just exploring; seems like best way to learn is to rewrite simple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, a method's implicit return value (if no explicit call to `return` is being made) is the return value of the last statement in that method. In this case that is the `for`, which apparently returns what it iterated over.